# PHP - Dynamically generated text - Adding "the" before certain countries

Tags: php, dynamic, text, countries

I doubt there is a PHP function for this, but I'd like to at least ask just in case something does exist.

I'm building a site which relies on the user's country, and that country is being automatically inserted into the content of the web page a couple of times. A basic example:

```
<?php echo "Find shoes in ".$country; ?>
```

Prints:

> Find shoes in UK

My problem is that the above sentence doesn't sound grammatically correct, and I believe it should read:

> Find shoes in the UK

It is *the* United Kingdom, just like you have *the* United States of America or *the* Netherlands etc.

I can't just add the word "the" into the sentence because "Find shoes in the France" obviously doesn't make sense.

Is there any way around this, or will I just have to go through all 200+ countries and work out which ones need the additional word echoing out?

Thanks

Comment: I Think using shorthand for country do not require word `'THE'` you can use like this `(USA or U.S.A.)`.
Any way if you want to add it you have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

this sort of language would reflect the word count i think ... i havent thought of all countries of course :) but a general rule of thumb, try doing

```
<?php echo "Find shoes in ".((str_word_count($country) == 1) ? 'the ' : '') . $country; ?>
```

bit hacky but i think that would actually work language wise? as those countries which require a 'the' prefix would **most likely** have more than one word.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and see how it works out. I was also thinking that I could look for an "s" at the end of the country, eg: Philippines should be "the Philippines". Don't know if this is true for all countries though :)

Comment: I don't think this will work very well in general.  For example, "Costa Rica" (not "The Costa Rica"), and "The Netherlands" (not "Netherlands").  Probably a better heuristic would be to check if the name has the word "of" or ends with "s". http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/article4c.html

Comment: i would add that also, as pluralisation of the word would indicate it would need a 'the' prefix also.

Comment: in the case of costa rica, another rule you could add is it the word ends in a vowel. its getting messier now though!

Comment: Looks like I've opened myself a can of worms here. Found this article on BBC website:- http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-18233844 - according to this the correct term for Gambia is "The Gambia", but "the Ukraine" as I have always called it is incorrect :( I think manual has to be the only way forward unfortunately

Comment: Oh BTW here is some pretty detailed discussion of this issue: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name
Especially check out the answer which starts with "IMO, it's all about plural and singular."

Answer (score 0):

This may be something to consider - write a quick script that checks each sentence against the After the Deadline API.

http://www.afterthedeadline.com/api.slp

Then build an array of the results - may save a bit of time over a manual process.